# Determining the type of List entries

Tags: java, generics

I have a `List<?> list`in Java.
Is there a way to determine the type of the contents of that list at runtime when the list is empty?

Comment: See this about type erasure in Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: So I assume the answer is "no".

Comment: @tob: Tell us more about what is it that you're trying to do. Suppose you can get the type parameter. What then?

Comment: When the list is empty, there is no "content", so how would it be possible to get the type of the non-existent content?

Comment: That's my problem. I cannot get it. It's a very generic class I am using.

Comment: I thought the compiler would somehow preserve the type even if I am handing over a `List<String>` to a method with signature `void someMethod(List<?> list)`. According to wheaties' comment, I was wrong.

Comment: @wheaties: Please put your rewrite your comment as an answer so that I am able to accept it.

Comment: @tob: This information is not included in the compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't figure out the type due to erasure -- in fact, even if the list is not empty you still can not reliably determine what the what the list really is.

Let's say right now your List<?> contains 2 elements: a Double and and Integer ... it would be nontrivial to figure out that it might be a List<Number> ... and even then, it may really be a List<Object> and someone could add a String later.

Furthermore, let's say it's really a List<List<String>>.  The most you'll figure out without attempting to recurse is that it's a List<List<?>>.

There is a bright side .  Depending on your situation, you may be able to use Type Tokens to work around erasure in a typesafe way.  There's a great post here: http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's at least one object in the list, to get the type of the list - `list.get(0).getClass().getSuperclass.getName();`

To get the type of an individual object - `list.get(0).getClass().getName();`

Comment: Depending on what is actually desired, `getClass()`, may not work. A `List<Animal>` may contain a `Dog`, but it's not a `List<Dog>`.

Comment: I would like to be able to do this on an empty list. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can iterate over each object in the list, and call the .getClass() method and print out its classname (or do various things based on the class it is).

e.g.,

```
for (Object o : list) {
   if (o.getClass().equals(MyClass.class)) {
      MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
      //do something with myClass etc etc
   }
   //...more if statements?
}
```

Comment: I would like to be able to do this on an empty list. Question edited.

Comment: type erasure will prevent the info you from getting the info you want to obtain at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As Chii says, you can iterate over each element.  Other than that, you can't know because technically you can put *any* object in a `List`.

e.g.,

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Integer(1));
    list.add(new Integer(2));
    list.add("string");
    list.add(new Double(0.2));
```

In the above example, what would the type of `list` be?  There isn't an answer to that question.

Comment: o alquimista: `tob` is asking for generics. According to generics: Once you have mentioned that the list can hold instance of x then your list can not have instance of y

Comment: @Rakesh: it _can_ if you ignore warnings, use raw types/unchecked conversion, etc. That's precisely why you shouldn't, but you can, if you really want to, or by accident.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not empty then `froadie` is correct
but if the list is empty then according to `Type erasure` it is impossible to find the type of object a List can have.

In java,

```
ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Float> lf = new ArrayList<Float>();
if (li.getClass() == lf.getClass()) // evaluates to true
  System.out.println("Equal");
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure