# How to reclaim the generic type you declared an arraylist to be in Java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I was just playing around and a thought came to my mind and I decided I want to try it:
Make an ArrayList that holds more ArrayLists.

For example, I created an ArrayList called intList that holds ints, then filled it with values. After that I did a stringList one and filled it too. Then I made an ArrayList that holds other ArrayLists called aList and added intList and stringList to it.

Now the problem I faced was if I was retrieving objects from aList, it would not recognize if the generic type was int or string.

Here is the code I tried:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

List<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

     ArrayList<int> intList = new ArrayList<int>();
     intList.add(1);
     intList.add(2);
     intList.add(3);

     ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     stringList.add("One");
     stringList.add("Two");
     stringList.add("Three");

     list.add(intList);
     list.add(stringList);

     for(ArrayList lst : list) {
      for(ArrayList lt : lst) {
       System.out.println(lt);
      }
     }
    } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the type of List entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566541/determining-the-type-of-list-entries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has "generic type erasure", meaning that the type parameters to generics are "erased". Once you create an `ArrayList<T>` there's no way to find out what `T` was.

Answer (score 1):

Only class types can be used as generic type parameters, so you can't have an `ArrayList<int>`.  Use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead.

In addition, the types used in your loops are wrong.  Since `list` is a list of lists of values, `lst` is a list of values, which means that your `lt` variable will be either an integer or a string, not another `ArrayList`.

The deeper problem here is that you're still using raw types, so the compiler can't find that error for you.  You should declare `list` as something like `List<List<? extends Object>>`.  That way you can add both an `ArrayList<Integer>` and an `ArrayList<String>` to it, and extract the values as type `Object` within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since no type information is stored in generic type, you could get element from sub-list and check it's type:

```
for(ArrayList subList : list) {
    if (subList.size() > 0) {
        Class elementClass = subList.get(0).getClass();
        // do something else with it
    }
}
```

But:

1. It will not work, if subList is empty
2. Generally, the concept of storing several lists of different types in another list looks rather strange.

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure means that at runtime, the type is erased.  That's why you can cast from one generic to another:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
        public static void main(String [] args){
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList list2 = (ArrayList)list;
                list2.add(new Integer(5));
                System.out.println(list2.get(0).getClass());
        }
}
```

Will output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<ArrayList<?>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();

     ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     intList.add(1);
     intList.add(2);
     intList.add(3);

     ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     stringList.add("One");
     stringList.add("Two");
     stringList.add("Three");

     list.add(intList);
     list.add(stringList);

     for(ArrayList<?> lst : list) {
      for(Object lt : lst) {
       System.out.println(lt);
      }
     }
    } 
}
```